# Wrong Resolutions after NVidia Driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, display

I have some issues with the NVidia Driver.
When I have installed the Ubuntu 14.04 the screen resolution could not detect the mode 1280x1024. I have created the mode 1280 x 1024 using xrandr. 
After installing the NVidia Driver I am not able to set the resolution to 1280x1024. Wrong resolutions are detected.

if I run xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1152 x 864, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024_60 (0x26f)  108.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1456 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x27a)  108.9MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.6KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1060           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024_75.00 (0x27d)  138.5MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock   80.2KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1069           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x1024_59.00 (0x27f)  107.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   62.5KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1059
```

When I try to add the new mode:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

My Connections is not DVI since I am using an adapter to D-sub.

Comment: What GPU do you have ?

Comment: Nvidia Geforce 8800GTS

Comment: Do you have this sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

Comment: Also can you set the mode in the nvidia-settings under display config open advanced and adjust the values of viewport in/out and save

Comment: Cant do it..... I can not hange the vieport out.

Comment: To change from terminal sudo nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1280x1024 {ViewPortOut=+1280x10240+0, ViewPortIn=1280x1024 }"

Comment: Change dfp-1 for the name of the display, find it in nviaia-settings wher you change resolution, it is in brackets at the end of selection option

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, open this file

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And add this line to the device section

```
Option"ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
```

Then reboot

Comment: Wow, finally I got it to work - thanks! Tip: If you are like me, an on-off Ubuntu user you may find it confusing that there is no xorg.conf file - just create the file from [this template](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) and add the above solution.