# New Nvidia driver install-update-display still wrong

Tags: nvidia

3rd try at installing Ubuntu-mate correctly.
I've updated Nvidia drivers using the Software & Updates >Other driver settings

Also added an additional PPA
http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/xbuntu xenial main

to get the very latest driver 375.20

I've applied changes and rebooted, but no change.
My resolution is still wrong.(low resolution, wrong format)
What do you need to do to make the driver's update your display?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have also tried this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/517238/wrong-resolutions-after-nvidia-driver

Comment: have you activated the driver? Search for additional drivers on the dash

Comment: Thanks. When you apply changes, isn't the driver activated by default?

Comment: ok, enabled Fast boot, Disabled Secure Boot in UEFI-BIOS, now my display is correct. But why?